# Cant change color space of image texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, baking, uv-image-editor

i just baked a moon texture on a new texture but the problem is now for the displacement , i cant change the color space to non colour this leads to some problem in the displacement , as you can see the color space option is blured

[image: colo]

Comment: Try saving the image to a file.

Comment: that made it work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not my awnsers it belongs to @scurest , i saved the image as a png and it worked